# PHP Repalce text tags with another value that i have in array

Tags: php, arrays, tags, str-replace

I have this text:

```
$text = "Welcome {name}, this is your email address: {email}";
```

I want to replace the {name} and {email} tags at once, not one by one using `str_replace("{name}","John",$text)`

I already have the replace output this way:

```
$values_to_replace = array('name'=>'John','email'=>'blabla@gmail.com');
```

How to make it work to repalce whole text from one shot using the given `$values_to_replace` ?

Comment: Can you change the array to be `array('{name}'=>'John'`?  It will make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several ways:

First here is strtr(). It takes an key=>value array and replaces all occurences of key with value.

```
$values = array('name'=>'John','email'=>'blabla@gmail.com');
$text = "Welcome {name}, this is your email address: {email}";

$replacements = array();
foreach ($values as $name => $value) {
  $replacements['{'.$name.'}'] = $value;
}
var_dump(strtr($text, $replacements));
```

Second str_replace() supports array for both the $search and $replace arguments.

```
$values = array('name'=>'John','email'=>'blabla@gmail.com');
$text = "Welcome {name}, this is your email address: {email}";  

$search = array_map(
  function($placeholder) {
    return '{'.$placeholder.'}';
  },
  array_keys($values)
);
var_dump(str_replace($search, $values, $text));
```

The third option is interesting, if you like to handle all {something} occurrences. This requires a regular expression and logic so preg_replace_callback is needed.

```
$values = array('name'=>'John','email'=>'blabla@gmail.com');
$text = "Welcome {name}, this is your email address: {email}";      

$replacer = function($match) use ($values) {
  if (isset($values[$match['name']])) {
    return $values[$match['name']];
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('(\\{(?P<name>[a-z\d]+)\\})i', $replacer, $text));
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but i prefer AbraCadaver's answer, is more easy and simple to use. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Since you can change the array keys to match the text to replace, then it's this easy:

```
$values_to_replace = array('{name}'=>'John','{email}'=>'blabla@gmail.com');
$text = str_replace(array_keys($values_to_replace), $values_to_replace, $text);
```

Or as Sébastien has shown.

To answer your comment, there are several ways, Sébastien's being one.  Here's another:

```
$search = explode(',', '{'.implode('},{', array_keys($values_to_replace)).'}');
$text = str_replace($search, $values_to_replace, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, and also will replace the values even if is not in same order.

Comment: Anyway, can u make it work if is not possible to change it as `array('{name}'=>'John'` ? you will make my day

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` can take arrays as parameters:

```
$text = "Welcome {name}, this is your email address: {email}";

$from = array("{name}", "{email}");
$to = array("John", "blabla@gmail.com");

$new_text = str_replace( $from , $to, $text );
```